# Loops running infinitely for big inputs

Tags: c, loops, do-while, cs50

I am self learner, I am working on a population growth problem, and I came across the issue of loop running infinitely when I enter a big ending number that I want to reach.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int n;

    do {
        n = get_int("Enter the starting size of your llamas: ");
    } while (n <= 8);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int j;

    do {
        j = get_int("Enter the Ending size of your llamas: ");
    } while (j <= n);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int k = 0;

    do {
        n = n + (n/3) - (n/4);
        printf("The number is %i\n", n);
        k++;
    } while (n != j);

    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("The number is %i\n", k);
}
```

The answer is supposed to be the number of years it takes to reach the end size llamas, but I am not able to put in big numbers of end size, can you help me figure out what is wrong, maybe in my math or a sign. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: So what numbers did you enter, and what do all those `printf` lines print?

Comment: What happens if `n` is smaller than `j` but `n + (n/3) - (n/4)` is larger than `j`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large numbers, `n` is incremented by more than `1` at each iteration, so it is possible than it becomes larger than `j` without being equal to it first.

Change the test `while(n != j);` to `while(n < j);`

Comment: Also, for `n < 9` that could be an infinite loop when `n/3 == n/4` (because of the integer division, which truncates), specifically for `n = 1, 2, 4, 5, 8`.

Comment: @dxiv: yes, but the input loop iterates `while (n <= 8);`

Comment: Good catch, I missed that part.